# Выборка другого поля, но если только текущее поле имеет номер

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица в базе данных (пример):

```
id| f1 | f_new | f_alt | status
1 | 13 |       |       | active
2 | 12 |  13   |       | archive
```

И есть запрос (пример)

```
SELECT * FROM `table`  WHERE f1 = '12' or f_alt = '12'
```

Вопрос следующий:
возможно ли в запросе узнать, что строка имеет **не пустое поле** `f_new` и затем выбрать строку по значению из `f_new`, т.е. `f_new` = `f1` (`id1`), и не выбирать строку `id2`

UPD. Есть проблема, если допустим таблица выглядит так (нужно достать активную стоку, т.е. `id3` :

```
id| f1 | f_new | f_alt | status
1 | 13 |   14  |       | archive
2 | 12 |   13  |       | archive
3 | 14 |       |       | active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where f1=(select f_new from table where f1=12)
```

Совсем простой вариант, не учитывающий, например, что значения в полях не уникальны.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, обновил, есть проблема

Comment: select * from table where status='active' или я не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: @ka5itoshka Если же вам надо пробежать всю цепочку f1=12, f_new=13->f1=13, f_new=14->f1=14,f_new=null, то тут простым SQL не обойдешься. Придется писать рекурсивную функцию, либо хранимкой, либо в коде.

Comment: обойдусь тогда. Спасибо ещё раз!